# Toggling the UILabel text on a UIButton programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I created the following outlet

```
IBOutlet UIButton *oneButton;
```

and the following method when a button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = sender.titleLabel.text;
    if ([digit isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        oneButton.titleLabel.text = @"11";
    } else if ([digit isEqualToString:@"11"])
    {
        oneButton.titleLabel.text = @"1";
    }
}
```

So basically I want to toggle the title of the button between 1 and 11, whenever pressed. By putting breakpoint, I see that the program goes through the line oneButton.titleLabel.text = @"11"; but the title never actually changes. oneButton is connected to the file's owner in the IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
[oneButton setTitle:@"11" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```